# A problem when releveling a factor to the default order?

Tags: r, factors, levels

I have this df

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:3)
```

converted to a factor

```
df$x = factor(df$x)
```

the levels by default are

```
str(df)
```

now let's make level 2 as the reference level

```
df$x = relevel(df$x,ref=2)
```

everything till now is ok. but when deciding to make the level 1 again as the default level it's not working

```
df$x = relevel(df$x,ref=2)

str(df)


df$x = relevel(df$x,ref=1)

str(df)
```

Appreciatethe help.

Comment: On the modified levels try `df$x <- relevel(df$x, ref=2)` again. It takes the second argument, which is obviously changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?relevel`,

```
     ref: the reference level, typically a string.
```

I'll key off of "typically". Looking at the code of `stats:::relevel.factor`, one key part is

```r
    if (is.character(ref)) 
        ref <- match(ref, lev)
```

This means to me that after this expression, `ref` is now (assumed to be) an `integer` that corresponds to the *index* within the levels. In that context, your `ref=1` is saying to use the first level by its index (which is already first).

Try using a string.

```r
relevel(df$x,ref=1)
# [1] 1 2 3
# Levels: 2 1 3
relevel(df$x,ref="1")
# [1] 1 2 3
# Levels: 1 2 3
```

Comment: FYI, this means that your initial `ref=2` is also suspect ...